# Is it possible to pull back a natural transformation?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose that a 2-category $\mathcal{C}$ has strict pullbacks and one has maps $f:F\to C$, $g_0,g_1:G\to C$ and a natural transformation $\gamma:g_1\implies g_0$. Is there a good notion of a pullback transformation $f^*\gamma$. If so, I would expect its codomain to be $$f^*g_1\times_G f^*g_0\to f^*g_1\to F$$ and similarly for the domain.

If there is, is the need for the extra pullback here (over $G$) connected to the second layer of pullbacks in a 2-categorical descent diagram (relative to quotients in a 1-cat, which only require a kernel pair=1 layer of pullbacks)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a good notion of a pullback transformation, but its domain and codomain aren't what you guessed; rather one asks for a map from $f^*(g_0) \to f^*(g_1)$ and a 2-cell filling the resulting triangle over G.  The existence of such a pullback transformation is also not automatic from the existence of pullbacks, but requires $f$ to be a fibration (and the existence of all such pullbacks is equivalent to $f$ being a fibration).  This characterization of fibrations is studied in Peter Johnstone's paper "Fibrations and partial products in a 2-category".